# Move "Mod" link to the right side

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools

I've recently been elected as a moderator to [ruSO](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour) and my regular-user's muscle memory gives me some fails. In particular since the "Mod" link was added on the left part of the block of links under the post, I misclicked for the "Edit" link and accidentally (but very often) click the "Share" link.

> [image: Move Mod to the right]

**Could we please move the Mod link to the right side of the block?**

I think that old mature moderators will deny this request (since they already got used to the link location), but because moderators can lose their diamonds (even the staff). And there are many sites on SE where the user elected on one site is still a regular user on another. I hope that in the distant future my request will give more profits than drawbacks.

An old one similar feature request (FR) on ruSO.meta from another elected moderator: [Переставить модераторскую кнопку в конец списка](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6238/176217)

Comment: But .... this will brake my muscle memory ....

Comment: @rene Please think about other people, about all future mods :) See the last paragraph in my Q.

Comment: People in general don't like moving their cheese. When SE doing it by force they don't really have a choice, but here they do.

Comment: @rene gifting bans via muscle memory xDDD

Comment: The only real solution is to copy the link to both locations, so _nobody's_ happy.

Comment: @goldPseudo [probably the best solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5AH4.png).

Comment: Well, you can get used to everything, but it's more logical when additional functionality is added without changing the location of the previous functionality.  It's one thing you get used to dragging the mouse even more to the right for one button, and another thing you need to get used to the location of all the buttons again. Also If moderator lose his romb he need to get used the locations of all the buttons again